# Remove elements from python list

Tags: python, list, element

I'm trying to understand the logic here, why this code doesn't remove all elements in the list?

```
int_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in int_lst:
    int_lst.remove(i)
    print(int_lst)

print(int_lst)  #Output: [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: You're modifying the list while looping through it. Because of this, it may skip some elements (`2, 4, 6`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove an element, everything after that element effectively moves back one place. But the iterator doesn't know that: it just advance the pointer to the next element, skipping what should have been the next value bound to `i`.

In detail, `i` starts at 1. You remove it, and now 2 is in the current position of the iterator. The iterator advances, and now 3 is in the current position and bound to `i`.

In other words, every time you remove an element, you effectively advance the iterator, *in addition* to the explicit advancement the iterator will perform.

Comment: Can you clarify more why "The iterator advances" without removing the current iteration! 
1st iteration: 1 removed and now int_lst=[2,3,4,5,6]
2nd iteration why not  2 not removed and will be int_lst=[3,4,5,6]

Comment: Maybe Python saves index of next element and when the previous element is removed, the next element take his element?

Comment: Because the iterator pointer exists separately from the list. After you remove 1, the pointer stays the same, but now the slot previously occupied by 1 is now occupied by 2, the one by 2 is now occupied by 3, etc. Once the body of the loop is done, now the iterator advances the pointer, which means it moves from the first slot to the second (which is now occupied by 3, not 2).

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are removing elements in the same list you are iterating through. You can easily fix it by avoiding this:

```
for i in list(int_lst):
    int_lst.remove(i)
```

Comment: I think this is a shallow copy

Comment: It is not a problem in this case